# how to pull all the repositories of a specific user ? what command should I use?

Tags: git, github

It's useful to be able to pull all the project at once , how should I do that ? thanks a lot ( how could I list all the repo of a user for example).

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)? You could probably use the list repositories section of the API to generate a list of all the repositories on the account then use that to generate `git pull` commands and run through each of the repositories and run that `git pull` command for every url.

Comment: "You could probably ... " Sure but haven't found yet.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard One of many solutions. There are many different ways to achieve this. I said "you could probably" meaning this is one of many possible solutions.